# Bootstrap image stretch to border on mobile only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With BS4, how can I stretch images to the screen border on mobile, while keeping the container in tact for all other elements (e.g. divs, h1, etc.)?

My problem is that I can easily change the container width with a media query, however that would affect all elements. Also, the images should not stretch to the border on desktop, which is why I cannot just use a generic container-fluid.

I also tried using negative margins like so:

```css
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .mobile-stretch {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/850x120" class="img-fluid mobile-stretch" />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure why but it only stretches to the left border, while maintaining the border on the right side. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you add container-fluid class in place of container, and the other stuff in container class centered?

```css
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  > .col,
  > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/850x120" class="img-fluid mobile-stretch" />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/850x120" class="img-fluid mobile-stretch" />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use the container-fluid because images should not stretch to the border on desktop. They should stretch to the border of the normal container as the other content on desktop. Thus also adding extra margins/padding to the container-fluid would not work on different widths.

Comment: you mean smth like this?
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)
.container {
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

Comment: No that's not what I mean. What I mean is that I want a container for all elements on min-width: 768px, and for max-width: 767px I want ONLY the img to be in a fluid container. So I guess the straight forward solution is using jQuery to add container-fluid class on a certain width.